# Why does following C++ meta-programming code gives compilation error for N=100 but runs fine for small N?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int x, int N> struct f{
        static const int res = x*(f<x, N-1>::res);
};

template <int x> struct f<x, 0>{
        static const int res = 1;
};

int main(){
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;++i)
                int a = (f<3, 100>::res);
}
```

If I change f<3, 100> to f<3, 10> code runs fine. But for 100 it gives following error:

```
.
.
.    
k.cpp:7:26:   recursively required from ‘const int f<3, 99>::res’
    k.cpp:7:26:   required from ‘const int f<3, 100>::res’
    k.cpp:16:23:   required from here
    k.cpp:7:19: error: initializer invalid for static member with constructor
    k.cpp:7:19: error: ‘f<3, 98>::res’ cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared
    k.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const int f<3, 99>::res’:
    k.cpp:7:26:   required from ‘const int f<3, 100>::res’
    k.cpp:16:23:   required from here
    k.cpp:7:19: error: initializer invalid for static member with constructor
    k.cpp:7:19: error: ‘f<3, 99>::res’ cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared
    k.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const int f<3, 100>::res’:
    k.cpp:16:23:   required from here
    k.cpp:7:19: error: initializer invalid for static member with constructor
    k.cpp:7:19: error: ‘f<3, 100>::res’ cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared
```

I am new to meta-programming. Though error looks like something related to `const` but it is not. Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: The error message begins by something like:
*"warning: overflow in expression; result is -808182895 with type 'int'"*.

Comment: You may rename `f` into `exponential` BTW.

Comment: `3 ** 100` doesn't even fit in `uint64_t`...

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, but I thought it'd do some computations, doesn't matter if result overflows. But it gave very weird and kind of unrelated error message. Now I get it. But still these error messages are in my opinion least helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Enable your warnings and read the error output carefully:

```
warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
         static const int res = x*(f<x, N-1>::res);
                                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
         static const int res = x*(f<x, N-1>::res);
                          ^~~
```

For large enough values of `N` you will have a *signed integer overflow*, which is **undefined behavior** in a run-time context and produces a **compile-time error** in a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

If I try `int a = (f<3, 20>::res);` I get

```
warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow
```

Making the `int` a `long long` gets over this and gives 3486784401 for `f<3, 20>`.

This can cope up to `f<3, 39>` with 4052555153018976267 and then overflows.

Moral: warnings are helpful.